# Retrieve native queries from properties

Tags: spring-boot

I'm wondering how to retrieve my native queries from spring-boot properties file.

I tried to use @Value and error. Then I tried to write the following:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<FooModel, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "${sql.queries.native.acquiredata}")
    Boolean acquireData();
}
```

But I got:

```
2020-04-07 15:15:00 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2020-04-07 15:15:00 - ERROR: syntax error nearby "$"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getProperty() method of environment object?

Comment: Can you post an example, please?

Comment: Of course, Use Environment object and initialize it using @Autowired then using the object call the method getProperty and then pass the property name in String format and it will return the specific vlue for that property

Comment: _"The blank final field env may not have been initialized"_ Error when using Autowired in the repository. Without Autowired, using _"public static final Environment env = null"_, then I get _"The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression"_ when trying to assign the value to the native query with _"env.getProperty("sql.queries.native.acquiredata")"_. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you importing this from springframework.env.core? And have you tried using new Environment () ?

Comment: "The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression" And yes I'm importing from springframework.env.core